# generate all combinations from 3 numbers

Tags: python

To generate all permutations of 3(or more) numbers in python, itertools.permutations can be used.
How can I generate combinations in batches of two.

For ex. : input list of numbers : `[1, 2, 3]`
and output: `[1,2], [2,3], [1,3]`

Comment: `itertools.combinations(li,2)`

Comment: i dont know why im getting negative votes, there hasnt been any question like this on SO before...

Comment: @AbhishekThakur - I don't think people downvoted this because it is a dupe (in fact, I think the proposed dupe isn't really a good one).  Downvoting for asking a dupe is against the spirit of this site. Instead, I think you got downvoted because you didn't demonstrate enough effort to solve the problem yourself.  While I personally will usually just vote to close the question for this, some people take it more seriously and downvote.  That or they don't have enough reputation to vote to close the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list(combinations(lst, 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
>>> [list(x) for x in combinations(lst, 2)]
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
itertools.combinations(iterable, r)
```

Example:

```
for x in itertools.combinations([1,2,3],2):
    print x
```